# Form Validation controls work when thy should not

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I have a webform(`asp.net4.5 C#`).

This form is a simple login page. and I validate the user login and password text boxes using asp.net validation controls.

This form has a Register button.

If user do not put a valid user name, validation control message shows as expected.

I have set up the `ValidationGroup`  property for the `Username  textbox` and and the button to "`GroupOne`".

The problem is when user click on a link button(`logout link button`) still validation control message shows up.

I know I can set `CauseValidation` property of this control to `false` to fix this but the question is why while this control is Not part of the `validationGroup` still it affected the validation.

Here is related code:

```
<asp:LinkButton id="logoutlink" runat="server" OnClick="logoutlink_Click">Logout</asp:LinkButton>
<td>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" runat="server" Width="100%" ValidationGroup="registerGroup"></asp:TextBox>
</td>
<td style="width: 208px">
    <asp:Button ID="btnRegister" Text="Register" runat="server" OnClick="btnRegister_Click" ValidationGroup="registerGroup"></asp:Button>
</td>
```

Comment: Please show us the code.

Comment: Added code. maybe Validation group  does not stop server side validation?

Comment: Is it possible the controls are inside a `<form>` ? Maybe it should be placed outside of it.